# What is the opposite of a catalyst and examples?

Tags: combustion, catalysis, reaction-control

I remember a while ago I heard of something that slowed reactions and was effectively the opposite of a catalyst. What is this called? Also would appreciate examples and an explanation of their uses just for curiosity. (I think the one I heard of was used to prevent spontaneous combustion)

Comment: Also there is "poison" which reduce the effect of catalyst.

Comment: Whatever answer you'll get there is not a real opposite of a catalyst. That would mean to force the reaction to take a more difficult path. Obviously, that is not possible from a mechanicist point of view. Still, the overall effect of reducing the reaction rate is a true thing.

Answer (score 1):

The opposite of a catalyst is essentially an inhibitor. From IUPAC's gold book [Gold book](https://doi.org/10.1351/goldbook.I03034)

> **inhibition**:
> The decrease in rate of reaction brought about by the addition of a substance inhibitor), by virtue of its effect on the concentration of a reactant, catalyst or reaction intermediate. For example, molecular oxygen and p-benzoquinone can react as 'inhibitors' in many reactions involving radicals as intermediates by virtue of their ability to act as scavengers toward these radicals.

Then there is a term called **negative catalyst**, and there are various opinions as to how they work.  [Journal of Chemical Education](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ed046p185.2)